# Google Spreadsheet Query Return Empty Cells

Tags: c#, google-api, google-docs

Am trying to set return-empty to true in Google API for C# .NET
So I can write to empty cell from my C# app.
Unable to figure out how to set Google.GData.Spreadsheets.ReturnEmtpyCells to true.
In C#.

Could someone provide the syntax for my to set this parameter to 'true" in my query?

Have spent hours looking and experimenting without success.
Amateur hobbiest programmer.

Keywords:  Google spreadsheet .NET API return empty return-empty returnempty C# "C sharp"

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
CellQuery query = new CellQuery("your query");
query.ReturnEmpty = ReturnEmtpyCells.yes;
```

Please note that there's a typo in ReturnEmtpyCells that is going to be [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/detail?id=485) soon.